# SQL Server Agent - Retrying/resuming failed steps of job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, package, bids

I created an sql server agent job that consists of steps that are calls to ssis packages.

Let's say that the job is being executed and one of the steps (that is a ssis package) has a file system task/sql task etc that fails. Is there any way that can I retry/rerun this particular package step (file system task/sql task etc) and then go on with my execution of the rest of the job steps after I fix my error? I know that you can retry certain sql server agent jobs and steps but I can't find any way to retry this step and resume my execution in case something inside the package fails.

And I also want to know if there is any way to disable certain package steps from the sql server agent "level" - without having to open Data tools.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the job properties, and into the step that contains the SSIS package.  Go to the Advanced tab, and you can modify the number of `Retry Attempts` for that step.

Comment: I thought that this Retry Attempts was for the whole package, so I will have to try it out if it applies when a step inside the package fails. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You could always put some error handling into the package in question. If an exception occurs, it will be handled accordingly allowing the other packages to continue. I always handle exceptions within the packages and log exceptions to a table.

In relation to your other question:
"And I also want to know if there is any way to disable certain package steps from the sql server agent "level" - without having to open Data tools. "

You could always go down the PowerShell route, create a script that takes a parameter. The parameter specifying whether or not you want a specific package to run.

If you want to skip certain steps within the package then you would have to create some sort of precedent constraint that acts on a variable you have set.

Comment: I have implemented some error handling inside the package. So my question really is if I can only work with my package - steps inside the package and not on SQL server agent. I will have to check out the script with the parameter, it sounds exactly like what I need. Thank you!